# Dynamic Filtering of list in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a java application that receives realtime data (Kafka/Kafka Streams) from sources. In my case study, I need to filter the names that is part of my list. The list has 10 million names initially.

My first problem is to know what is the best way and/technology to use to have more efficient/faster processing time.

Second problem is how to update or delete some names in the list?

Answer (score 0):

> need to filter the names that is part of my list

Kafka Streams DSL has a `filter()` function.

> how to update or delete some names in the list

Not clear where "your list" exists.

Kafka topics themselves doesn't do update/delete, as they are append-only. KTable's do, and updates are done by sending a matching key and new value; deletes are done with a matching key and null value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll look that Ktable option but what I am thinking now is to have an external database thru web service but I don't know if that is the best option

Comment: KTables can be queried by a feature called Interactive Queries. KTables have RocksDB as their default storage. Using external databases is possible, but adds latency